# How do you deal with changes to Work Flow Definition in WWF, Windows Workflow 4.0

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

We currently have an issue where we have existing client data on Workflow instances. When we make updates to the Workflow Definition, it seems to invalidate existing workflows, even if it is small changes.

What is the best method to migrate existing instances persisted to the DB to the new workflow definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a migration per se. At least it shouldn't be.

Basically existing, persisted instances should end their execution on the version they began with and new ones should be stamped and executed with the new version. But this all depends on the strategy you choose for it.

That's exactly what [WF4 versioning](http://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2012/10/11/side-by-side-versioning-of-workflow-services/) is for, in particular [WorkflowIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.Activities.WorkflowIdentity.aspx).

Unfortunately is a fairly undocumented WF4 feature (examples-wise at least) but you should easily figure it out with a quick search.

Here a couple more links for a blog series by Ron Jacobs: [1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rjacobs/2011/03/30/wf4-workflow-versioning-spike/) [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2011/04/13/wf4-versioning-spike-planning-for-change/)

Comment: Great stuff, that link looks promising! I'll try this in a bit and post how it works out. For now I consider this answered. Thanks! I have another issue I posted regarding serialization of Dynamic proxies and wf4 and I'm wondering if you may be able to help - http://stackoverflow.com/q/39629243/4584071